# Offset armature to body causes shaking and unwanted moves

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I followed a tutorial that told me to keep offset of the legs and arm to the spine. I did and it looks good when I move the spine, but now whenever I move a leg or a arm, the whole character move. See for yourself: [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dg4aAUN80TcNCeI5YBQh9CQqqDHX3npS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You didn't adjust the chain length of the IK constraints. Set 2 to each IK bone.

Comment: For the arms, probably you'll want to add shoulder bones so that the IK influence can stop on them lowering the chain length as @FFeller suggested